# I am unable to create a good mesh and rig for my character

Tags: mesh, rigging

I am trying to create a mesh and rig for my character.

I want the character to be active and animate it with some action, but the mesh and rig i am able to create is not allowing me to do that. The stomach is fat, so when the rig bends, it looks weird. The arms also are weird because shoulders are almost no existent. I know the edge flows are also incorrect in the mesh i made, that might be a problem as well.

https://blend-exchange.com/b/kA3ZA3oa

[image]

Comment: Tho the video topic is different, from `21:30` minute there is a rigging workflow fully explained: [Rigging video](https://youtu.be/zbsKewh8dpI?t=1290)

Comment: Hello and welcome. Asking for links to resources about X is considered off topic here, asking directly about X is encouraged though. If you can rephrase your question to focus on the specific difficulties you are encountering, rather that point you to some site, please [edit] your post so it can be reopened. As it stands it is not a good fit for this site.

Comment: What don't you like about the shoulder deformation and the belly? I'm more worried about his non-existing knees and elbows and too many sub-div levels  ;-) But with a few adjustments you can get a good deformation: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZIP1.jpg However, there still are a few clipping issues with the clothes. -- Or are you looking for cartoonish animation where he can scratch his head with a stretched arm?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Blunder, when i try this model on auto rigger app like mixamo and try some actions out, the stomach deformation gets very weird, its clipped and spreads from the sides. I am looking for a cartoonish animation but not stretching. I agree the knees and elbows are bad, will fix that so there is more room for deformation. Also looking at more tutorials online, i think my edge flows arent good enough for animation, so trying to learn how to create good edge flows. Do point me to it if you have a good resource.

Comment: Yes, Mixamo seems to have problems with the weights around the belly. But in Blender, you can use automatic weights to fix this. For the Rigify rig, I've just added a few edge loops for the toes (front of the feet), the arms, and the legs. And I've added a patch for the elbows and knees. That's only an inset and worked well with automatic weights. [Here](https://youtu.be/GxMz4HylQfU) is a more sophisticated version of such "patches".